# Определить параметры своего компьютера на C/C++

Tags: c++, c

На C/C++ для своего компьютера определить:
 - Тип компьютера
 - Конфигурацию
 - Объем ОЗУ
 - Размер ПЗУ
 - Версию ОС

Согласно вот такой таблице:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очень похоже, что требуется написать программу для DOS. А потому  просто обращайтесь в область памяти, где расположен BIOS и считывайте конфигурационные биты BIOS.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что явно учебное задание.

Comment: Какие типы компьютера имеются в виду?

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему, ваш преподаватель где-то раздобыл методичку родом из 80-x. Ищите старинные учебники под DOS типа Фигурнова, Фараонова и Немнюгина - там все это описано.

Answer (score 1):

Странно, что язык C указан, без включения ассемблерных вставок это невозможно решить
Вам видимо нужен эиулятор DOS и под него компилятор C тех времен, типа borland C.
ну и вставочку делать на подобии

```
push es
push si
mov ax,40h
mov es,ax
mov si,10h
mov ax,es:[si]
pop si
pop es
```

Все, в `AX` у вас эти 2 байта, которые теперь можно загружать в переменную C и разбирать как душе угодно по битам. Ну или прямо на ассемблере разбирать.

Comment: Выдает ошибку: "недопустимая ссылка на 16-разрядные данные в "второй операндр"" в строке "mov ax,es:[si]"

Comment: А вы чем компилируете. Судя по всему у вас компилятор в 32 разрядном режиме. А во времена DOS когда все это работало, 32 разрядного режима еще не изобрели... нужен 16 битный компилятор и главное, это потом должно запускаться в реальном (не защищенном) режиме процессора. Ну или в полной эмуляции реального режима

Comment: Как на счет использования acm/macm?

Comment: У вас эмулятор DOS есть под рукой ? потому как если его нет - то и смысла делать эту программу нет. В защищенном режиме совершенно другая адресация памяти и конфигурации BIOS по адресам 40:10 просто нет. ОС эти области памяти приложениям просто не покажет. Хотя конечно можно загрузить комп в чистый DOS ... masm/tasm могут делать программы для 16 битного режима. gcc может. но надо то на чем их потом запустить

Comment: Эмулятора нету. Нужно сделать средствами MVS.

Comment: MVS - это MS Visual C ? или что. В общем я сказал условия при которых оно может работать - это должно работать в 16 битном, реальном режиме (ну или режиме виртуального 8086). Хотя может винда по старой памяти своим приложениям и дает обращаться по этим адресам. Ну попробуйте в 32 битном. ES=0, ESI=0x410, EAX=ES:[ESI]. Просто я последний раз с асмом работал во времена DOS, когда винды в помине не было. И тогда это было актуально